# NativeScript + angular app crashing on startup (android 11 - API 30)

Tags: android, angular, crash, nativescript

I have an app in NativeScript + Angular, when i put **targetSdkVersion** from 29 to 30 (as google needs) on **App_Resources\Android\app.gradle**, the app crashes on start and show nothing, just closes itself. I tryed so many things to fix, and nothing works. When i back **targetSdkVersion** to 29, the app works perfectly.

app.gradle

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion 30
  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 30
    generatedDensities = []
    multiDexEnabled true
  }
  aaptOptions {
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
  }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1"
}
```

package.json dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animation": "^4.0.0-beta.8",
    "@angular/animations": "~11.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "~11.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~11.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~11.0.0",
    "@nativescript/angular": "~11.0.0",
    "@nativescript/appversion": "^2.0.0",
    "@nativescript/core": "~7.0.0",
    "@nativescript/datetimepicker": "~2.0.0",
    "@nativescript/iqkeyboardmanager": "~2.0.0",
    "@nativescript/picker": "^3.0.1",
    "@nativescript/theme": "~2.3.3",
    "@nativescript/webpack": "^3.0.0",
    "@nstudio/nativescript-exoplayer": "^5.0.6",
    "@nstudio/nativescript-snackbar": "^2.1.0",
    "@ticnat/nativescript-searchable-select": "^1.0.7",
    "credit-card-type": "^9.1.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "nativescript-audio": "^6.2.0",
    "nativescript-dna-netservices": "^1.1.0",
    "nativescript-fontawesome": "^1.0.0",
    "nativescript-iap": "^8.0.3",
    "nativescript-screen-orientation": "^2.0.0",
    "nativescript-sentry": "^2.0.0",
    "nativescript-sqlite": "^2.6.4",
    "nativescript-ui-dataform": "^7.0.4",
    "nativescript-ui-sidedrawer": "~9.0.0",
    "nativescript-zip": "^4.0.2",
    "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.12",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.0",
    "xcode": "^3.0.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^11.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.0.0",
    "@nativescript/android": "7.0.1",
    "@nativescript/ios": "7.1.1",
    "@nativescript/schematics": "^10.1.0",
    "@nativescript/types": "7.0.0",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "~11.0.0",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.15",
    "codelyzer": "~6.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "ts-patch": "^1.3.2",
    "tslint": "~6.1.3",
    "typescript": "~4.0.0"
  }
```

Comment: Must be an issue with some of the plugins not working well with sdk30. It might be tiresome to check one by one, so try adding `<application android:allowNativeHeapPointerTagging="false">` to AndroidManifest.xml. If it doesn't fix the issue, you should devote some time into finding the exact plugin(s) that cause the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> Must be an issue with some of the plugins not working well with sdk30.
> It might be tiresome to check one by one, so try adding  to AndroidManifest.xml.
> If it doesn't fix the issue, you should devote some time into finding
> the exact plugin(s) that cause the problem.

Thanks **MishaMashina**! Putting *android:allowNativeHeapPointerTagging="false"* in my AndroidManifest.xml solved my problem.

In aditional, i had another problem with API 30 after solved the first one. i was taking the **ERR_ACCESS_DENIED** error when i tryed load content in a webView. And i solved it setting this properties on the code when loading the webView:

```
webView = args.object.android;
...
webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
webView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
```

Comment: Please fix grammar and capitalization issues